# PHP: pass variable to javascript method

Tags: javascript, php, html

***What I have:***

Try to pass variable to javascript method in such way:

```
$name = (string) $form->attributes()->name;
$show = 'show("'.$name.'")';
echo '<input type="radio" onclick="'.$show.'">'.$form['description'].'<br />';
print_r($show); // show("feedback")
...
<script>
function show(name) {
    //DEBUG HERE!
    ...
}
</script>
```

***What a problem:***

In browser's debugger I can see that into *show* method I've passed the whole form (means that argument name equals to the whole form).

***Question:***

*Why does it happen? How to pass to js-method only form's name?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just missing some quotes around it:

```
echo '... onclick="show(\"'.$name.'\")> ...';
```

Note the `\"` I put around `$name`. In your code, if `$name = "Foo"`, it would write `show(Foo)` instead of `show("Foo")`.

Comment: I've editted my code. Still not working. Please, see new version

Comment: You will now output `onclick="show("...")"`, which doesn't work because you can't use `"` in both places.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not escaping the string properly to be used by the JS function. Try escaping the strings like this:

```
$name = 'feedback';
$description = 'description';

//like this
echo '<input type="radio" onclick="show('. "'" . $name . "'" . ')">' . $description . '<br/>';

// or like this
echo "<input type=\"radio\" onclick=\"show(' . $name  . ')\">" . $description . "<br/>";

<script>
function show(name) {
  alert(name);
}
</script>
```

I hope this helps.